# TinyMCE Advanced newline problem

Tags: plugins, tinymce, plugin-tinymce

I am using TinyMCE Advanced plugin according to qTranslate in a wordpress 3.3 installation. **My question is:** why does tinymce translate visual editor new line ("enter" key) in a `<p>&nbsp;</p>` instead of `<br/>`?

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into Settings -> TinyMCE Advanced, and check the option `Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the HTML editor`.  This will allow you full control over those tags inside the HTML view.

For a single line break without overriding the editor, use `Shift+Enter`.

To override the editor and make `Enter` a single line break, put this into your `functions.php`:

```
function change_mce_options($init){
    $init["forced_root_block"] = false;
    $init["force_br_newlines"] = true;
    $init["force_p_newlines"] = false;
    $init["convert_newlines_to_brs"] = true;
    return $init;       
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init','change_mce_options');
```

This does not convert `shift+enter` into `<p></p>` however, and this will cause some strange behavior for already existing content (if you're inside an existing `<p>` it will give two lines instead of one), so I would strongly recommend getting used to `shift+enter` instead.

Comment: i do not understand your answer. I already use tinymce advanced, but I can't find the options where I can choose to use <br/> instead of <p>&nbsp;</p>

Comment: Edited comment to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

1) use soft returns (shift+enter) to insert `<br>` instead of paragraphs.
2) if you want to make intent in the beginning of sentence after 
 (SHIFT+ENTER), then you may need to use this custom code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139347/42702