# How avoid WP editor to change <br/> by &nbsp;

Tags: visual-editor, wp-editor

Ok this is an old question and i may receive classical answers :

- use soft key

  I can't, i also use JIG and it makes the soft key invalid when i use it to make the text slightly downard to feet with my image. Wich is precisly why i need to use br as it works good to make that. And by the way even if it would work the editor is erasing the soft key spacing as soon as i come back to edit my text. I got something else to do than constantly add soft key jumps each time i want to edit.
- disabble wpautop

  Well i was on that path but it has been told to me that i shouldn't. "Disabling autop for this is probably a bad idea, as it makes many more changes in how the editor content is processed, changes that most likely the poster will like to still take effect". Wich is right.

Basically i would like to be free to use < br/> in wordpress.

Thanks a lot by advance for your help.

Edit : Oh!!! I came here to edit my post, i added < br/> to get my lines under "use soft key" and "disabble wpautop", then i saved, then i opened edition again, and gosh !!! It keeps my < br/>s !!! So this is possible ! How ?

Answer (score 1):

Without an explicit example I can only guess that if inserting <br> is good enough for you then you can get the same effect by adding a class to the paragraph that is created by default to remove any margins and paddings from it. This of course is not a good semantic solution but I haven't seen many people actually caring about semantics.

The other option is to write some code and create a [br] shortcode to use wherever you need to insert a <br>. This plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/line-break-shortcode/ is a little stale but I can't think of any reason it should not work.

Comment: Thanks Mark ! I can't use the first solution because, if i understand well, this would mean that every paragraph would then have this caracteristic, and i need it only for some.

The second one works !
Funny thing is that it doesn't work before a JIG image but only after. Maybe because Jig uses a shortcode too. So i deal  with the spacing between a paragraph and the JIG playing with the image margin, then i move my floating text down thanks to the [br]. Anyway, it does the trick.

http://bradypus.fr/fr/premieres-grimpe text is now well positionned at the same level than the top of the image.

Comment: glad that it helped. about the first solution, no you don't need to have all the paragraphs like that, just have a class defined to be like that and apply the class to the patagraph, but I admit the shortcode is an easier to understand and to use, but in general if there is a layout problem the best thing is to solve it in CSS if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these details. I'll give a try to the first solution too. Semantic is not my strengh so... at least it sounds better than having a plugin.

I'd be glad to understand also how br can be conservated in coments of this site cause it lets think that there's a way to do it straight forward.

Anyway, thanks again !